# how to model status for a task in django model

Tags: python, django, model, status

In my `django` app, a `Task` can have `PENDING or FINISHED` `status`.Which is the best way to model this in a django Model?

```
class Task(models.Model):
    taskname = models.CharFiled(...)
    taskdate = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharFiled(...)
```

Is this the proper way? Ideally I would like to provide the user with a `dropdown list` from which he can choose the status.Can someone suggest how I can model this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be any type of field like `Char` or `Int` but you can provide list of choices to it which will show as dropdown in the html form.

Reference at [Model field Choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
    ('FR', 'Freshman'),
    ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
    ('JR', 'Junior'),
    ('SR', 'Senior'),
)
class Student(models.Model):
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                  choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES, default='FR')
```